# Adding wildcard in Authorized JS url in GCP to support tenants

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api

we have an integration with Google Drive and our customers are using the Google Drive Picker modal to select files from their Google Drive.

The issue is that we have many customers, each one have their own tenant.
For example:
https://stackoverflow.myCompany.ai
OR
https://salesforce.myCompany.ai

In GCP, under https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient
I am trying to add a single authorized URL which will be something like:
https://{}.myCompany.ai
But it doesn't work, wildcard also doesn't work

Any idea how I can add a single URL that will accept all tenants so that I won't need to add each customer tenant to the authorized JS urls?
Our domain is authorized.

Thanks!